# how to set textbox length when it set to be read only "false" in vb

Tags: vb.net

i just don't know how to set text length for a textbox when it set to read only "false"

```
the result i get is 98.888888 and i want to set to have only 4 digit to 98.88

i tried to set maxlength in textbox properties but is not working 

and Button1.click
if Length(textbox1.text) > 6 then
enter only six chars
else if Length(textbox1.text) < 6 then
enter up to six chars
also not working
```

can anyone tell me how to do that??

Comment: `98.88` is 5 digits. What platform are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Try Like This:

```
 TextBox1.Text = "98.8888888"

        If TextBox1.Text.Trim.Length > 5 Then

            TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text.Substring(0, 5)

        End If
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use  the validate event handler to format the text,  then something like this might work, textbox1.text = textbox1.text.tostring("n2").

Can't test it powers out using tablet

Answer (score 0):

Sometime it happen .. and I dont know why ..

So, we have to control it in Textbox Textchanged event ..

```
Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged

    TextBox1.Text = mid(TextBox.Text,1,Textbox1.MaxLength)

End Sub
```